# Particles hair rendering too dark

Tags: rendering, hair

Why is the texture on the arm hair rendering so dark?

[image]

Comment: Are the hair particles around that area more dense than the rest?  That could cause the problem.

Comment: No not really, I apply the hair particles to the entire body. So why would it only be dense around the right arm?

Comment: Did you add hairs in particle edit mode to the spot?  or did you comb those hairs down and the rest are standing up?